# Fail to define new endpoint on basicHttpBinding

Tags: wcf

I want to define two endpoint that will represent two different interfaces

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" >
    <endpoint 
        binding="basicHttpBinding" 
        bindingConfiguration="LargeData_basicHttpBinding" 
        contract="Contracts.IService1" />
    <endpoint 
        binding="basicHttpBinding" 
        bindingConfiguration="LargeData_basicHttpBinding" 
        contract="Contracts.IService2" />
    <endpoint 
        address="mex" 
        binding="mexHttpBinding" 
        contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

When I try to add the second endpoint for IService2, I can access only the service2 from the browser - and if I remove the service2 from the config file - I can access from the browser to service1 && service2.

What is my mistake ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not specifying any local/relative addresses for the endpoints! Therefore, they're both using the same base address / location of your virtual directory.

Try specifying a relative address for both:

```
<endpoint 
    address="Service1"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" 
    bindingConfiguration="LargeData_basicHttpBinding" 
    contract="Contracts.IService1" />
<endpoint 
    address="Service2"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" 
    bindingConfiguration="LargeData_basicHttpBinding" 
    contract="Contracts.IService2" />
```

Now you should be able to access both services, one at

```
http://yourserver/virtualdirectory/YourService.svc/Service1
```

and the other at

```
http://yourserver/virtualdirectory/YourService.svc/Service2
```

Comment: Ok, Thanks. But i added two .svc files - one for each Interface - and i can then use the http://yourserver/virtualdirectory/Service1.svc/    and http://yourserver/virtualdirectory/Service2.svc/    - is it right ?

Comment: @Yanshof: yes - but then you would need two separate `<service name="....."> ... </service>` sections inside your `<services>` in the web.config - one for each service/svc file, with one basicHttp endpoint.